# Deploy the global.asax file using wsp

Tags: 2010, solution-package

I need to make change to global.asax in custom STS . Since 7 applications use this STS, I would like to create a package ,so that it is deployed on all servers . Could anyone provide code or link where i can deploy the global.asax file using wsp ?

Comment: did you check this one http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6185a5f4-61e8-4746-be5e-f18a17780e42/placing-globalasax-file-using-wsp-package?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: yea i did check .